# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Order"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm pretty new to javascript, and I'm trying to create an e-commerce website. Currently, I am trying to get my order id to show on the return page, but I keep getting a **Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Order"** error. Below I have included what I have. I would really appreciate any help or advice on why I'm having this issue. Thank you!

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import CheckoutSteps from '../components/CheckoutSteps';
import {shipOrder, deliverOrder, returnOrder, detailsOrder, payOrder } from '../actions/orderActions';
import { ORDER_CREATE_RESET, ORDER_RETURN_RESET} from '../constants/orderConstants';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';

export default function DeliveryReturnScreen(props) {
    const orderId = props.match.params.id;
    const [sdkReady, setSdkReady] = useState(false);
    const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails);
    const { order, loading, error} = orderDetails;
    const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
    const { userInfo } = userSignin;
    const orderPay = useSelector((state) => state.orderPay);
    const {
      loading: loadingPay,
      error: errorPay,
      success: successPay,
    } = orderPay;
  
    const orderReturned = useSelector((state) => state.orderReturned);
    const {
      loading: loadingReturned,
      error: errorReturned,
      success: successReturned,
    } = orderReturned;
  
  
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    const addPayPalScript = async () => {
        const { data } = await Axios.get('/api/config/paypal');
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${data}`;
        script.async = true;
        script.onload = () => {
          setSdkReady(true);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      };
      if (
        !order ||
        successPay ||
        successReturned ||
        (order && order._id !== orderId)
      ) {
        dispatch({ type: ORDER_RETURN_RESET });
        dispatch(detailsOrder(orderId));
      }
      /* else {
        if (!order.isPaid) {
          if (!window.paypal) {
            addPayPalScript();
          } else {
            setSdkReady(true);
          }
        }
      }
      */
    }, [dispatch, orderId, sdkReady, successPay, successReturned, order]);
  
    const successPaymentHandler = (paymentResult) => {
        dispatch(payOrder(order, paymentResult));
    };

    
    const ReturnedHandler = () => {
        dispatch(returnOrder(order._id));
      };



  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <h1>Order {order._id}</h1>
       
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Replace this: `<h1>Order {order?._id}</h1>` instead of `<h1>Order {order._id}</h1>`

Comment: @davoodSandoghsaz that gave me a syntax error

Comment: Put this `<h1>Order {order && order._id}</h1>`

Comment: @davoodSandoghsaz unfortunately, it's still giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

When using `useParams`, you have to match the destructure

```
let { _id } = useParams();
```

to your path `"/order/_id"`.